# jquery hide text content in a tag, not the tag itself

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have a slider using this html syntax:

```
<div id="theatre">
    <a class="sliderImg" href="01.jpg" />some-text</a>
    <a class="sliderImg" href="02.jpg" />another-description</a>
    <a class="sliderImg" href="03.jpg" />whatever</a>
    <a class="sliderImg" href="04.jpg" />whatever</a>
</div>
```

What I need to do is to hide the text of the a tags not the a tags themselves.

I got this but doesn't work.

```
var imgCaptions = $("#theatre a.sliderImg").html();
$(imgCaptions).hide();
```

I can't add a span because I use the content for some AJAX. The structure has to remain.

Many thanks for your help. Merry Xmas!

Comment: why dont you just add span, <a class="sliderImg" href="01.jpg" /><span>some text</span></a> then hide, $("a.sliderImg span").hide();

Comment: I can't add a span because I use the content for some AJAX. The structure has to remain.

Comment: Do you need to be able to toggle the text; or just hide it entirely, for good?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
a.sliderImg {
    color: transparent;
}
```

You could also use the `user-select` CSS property to prevent the text being selected:

```
a.sliderImg {
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Or, possibly, use the `unselectable` attribute on the elements themselves:

```
<a unselectable="on" class="sliderImg" href="04.jpg">whatever</a>
```

Incidentally your HTML is malformed, the `/` should *not* be in the opening tag (that's only in the opening tag for void elements, such as `input` or `img`).

References:

- [`user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select).

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the text simply by using the `.text` method:

```
$(".sliderImg").text('');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5QME/

If you need to store the text for use later, set it as a data attribute on the parent anchor:

```
$(".sliderImg").text(function(i,v){
    return $(this).data('originalText', v), '';
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5QME/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can put extra tag ex. span around text inside a and hide the span 
 some-text

```
$('#teathre span').hide();
```

Comment: I can't add a span because I use the content for some AJAX. The structure has to remain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to hide just the text:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yw8w2/1/

```
$('#theatre a.sliderImg').map(function(){ $(this).text(''); });
```