# jquery selector inside a table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

here is my html code wordpress that makes a table in my plugin dash page:

```
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed exams">

    <thead></thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:exam">
        <tr class="alternate">
            <th class="check-column" scope="row">
                <input class="exam_cb" type="checkbox" value="22" name="exam[]"></input>
            </th>
            <td class="ID column-ID"></td>
            <td class="exam_name column-exam_name">

                this text is to be selected

                <span style="color:red"></span>
                <div class="row-actions">
                    <span class="subjects"></span>
                    <span class="settings"></span>
                    <span class="clone"></span>
                    <span class="users"></span>
                    <span class="uploads"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="total_user column-total_user"></td>
            <td class="date_create column-date_create"></td>
            <td class="short_code column-short_code"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="alternate"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="alternate"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="alternate"></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

with my jquery code i want to select **this text is to be selected**  only inside td:

```
$(".exam_cb").click(function() {

            $(this).parent("th").next("td").next("td").hide(); // hides td class exam_name
            $(this).parent("th").next("td").next("td").text().hide(); // not working
            $(this).parent("th").next("td").next("td").html().hide(); // not working
            $(this).parent("th").next("td").next("td").val().hide(); // not working
     });
```

what is wrong with me?

Comment: Maybe duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033200/jquery-hide-text-content-in-a-tag-not-the-tag-itself

Comment: use nextAll() instead of next()

Answer (score 0):

You need to select text node by filtering them by nodeType. and then wrap the content in dom element with css display none:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.exam_name').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');//wrap in span and hide the,
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y59pf4L8/)**

Comment: how to get this text as a variable for apply as html input tag value? the above example returns [object Object] as text.

Comment: @Nisu: if this answer was broadly the solution, please accept it. To do so, click on the tick icon on the left of the answer, so it turns green. This is how we thank people on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply hide on text() - you apply it on an HTML Element

```
$(this).parent("th").next("td").next("td").hide();
```

Thats causing a JS Error and hence none of your other statements after that is working

and `the same is true for val().hide() - A JS Error will be thrown`

```js
$(".exam_cb").click(function() {
   
    var columnmTo=$(this).parent("th").next("td").next("td");
  
    columnmTo.find('.selectedTest').addClass('highlight');
         
    columnmTo.find('.error').hide();
    
    columnmTo.find('.row-actions').hide();
 });
```

```css
span.highlight
{
font-weight:bold;
}

span.error
{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed exams">

    <thead></thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:exam">
        <tr class="alternate">
            <th class="check-column" scope="row">
                <input class="exam_cb" type="checkbox" value="22" name="exam[]"></input>
            </th>
            <td class="ID column-ID"></td>
            <td class="exam_name column-exam_name">

                <span class="selectedTest">this text is to be selected</span>

                <span class="error">Hello</span>
                <div class="row-actions">
                    <span class="subjects">a</span>
                    <span class="settings">b</span>
                    <span class="clone">c</span>
                    <span class="users">c</span>
                    <span class="uploads">d</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="total_user column-total_user"></td>
            <td class="date_create column-date_create"></td>
            <td class="short_code column-short_code"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="alternate"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="alternate"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="alternate"></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```